# Google Maps - Creating an infowindow which is larger than the map itself

Tags: javascript, maps

I have a seemingly simple task, but it turns out it's more complicated than I thought. I have a marker in the center of my google map which, when clicked, opens an infowindow. I'd like the infowindow to be bigger than the map, however when I set its dimensions too big, it just gets scrollbars instead of showing the whole thing:

http://jovansfreelance.com/test.php

Is there a way to get around this? I tried setting the height/width to important, messing with the overflow property etc, but nothing.

I suppose I could hack it by creating an absolutely positioned div which would open when the marker is clicked, and simulate an infowindow that way, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. The map has to remain the same size.